# VHDL don't care for integer

Tags: vhdl, best-practice

I am writing a reset for a vhdl statemachine that has an integer signal, which is initialized in the second state of the statemachine. However for completeness (assign every signal to avoid latches) I would like to assign a `don't care` value to the signal, so the synthesis tool has the most room for optimization.

Is there any way to assign a don't care value to a signal of the type `integer`?
(I know I could convert it to `signed`/`unsigned` and assign `(others => '-' )` however it feels more natural to write this code with integer, since this allows to write `if var=3 ...` instead of `if to_integer(var)=3 ...` or `if var=to_(un)signed(3, var'Length)...` which feels uncomfortable.

Of I can not assign `don't care`, what is the best practice, assign the value, that I will assign in the second state, leave it unassigned or others? (I would go with assigning the value from the second state early)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no "don't care" for integer; if you are modelling digital logic with X, Z, don't care etc, then numeric_std.signed/unsigned is the right way to go.

But look at the numeric_std package more carefully; most operators including `=` are overloaded with forms that allow mixing [un]signed and integer freely, so that `if my_unsigned_var = 3` just works...